# how to save the stack trace of a linux demon/service into an external file

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, stack-trace

I have a problem with printing the stack trace (back-trace) of a demon which is created for C++ application. service is based on /etc/init.d/ init script based architecture and I have seen several services followed the same to deliver applications as services in Linux. in this case when stopping my service by `service name stop` stack trace of the program is printing on the console. This backtrace contains the uncleaned memory map of the program. 
I just need to avoid printing this on the terminal and save it into a separate file till I fix the memory issues of the program.

**EDITED:**

- Can this do by adding more commands to the init script ?
- Is there any compilation option to avoid printing the program
  stack-trace after stopping the program ?
- Can a block of c/c++ source code use to handle this ?

Below is my `/etc/init.d/init` script.

```
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

cscored=${CSCORED-/opt/application-name/bin/cscore &}
prog=cscored
pidfile=${PIDFILE-/var/run/cscored/cscored.pid}
lockfile=${LOCKFILE-/var/lock/subsys/cscored}
RETVAL=0
STOP_TIMEOUT=${STOP_TIMEOUT-10}

start() {
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
        daemon  $cscored
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch ${lockfile}
        return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc  $cscored
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && rm -f ${lockfile} ${pidfile}
}
reload() {
    echo -n $"Reloading $prog: "
    if ! $cscored -t >&/dev/null; then
        RETVAL=6
        echo $"not reloading due to configuration syntax error"
        failure $"not reloading $cscored due to configuration syntax error"
    else
        # Force LSB behaviour from killproc
        LSB=1 killproc -p ${pidfile} $cscored -HUP
        RETVAL=$?
        if [ $RETVAL -eq 7 ]; then
            failure $"cscored shutdown"
        fi
    fi
    echo
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  status)
        status $cscored
    RETVAL=$?
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  condrestart|try-restart)
    if status $cscored >&/dev/null; then
        stop
        start
    fi
    ;;
  force-reload|reload)
        reload
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $prog {start|stop|restart|condrestart|try-restart|force-reload|reload|status|fullstatus|graceful|help|configtest}"
    RETVAL=2
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: Do you want to set up logging in your program? If so, you can use Log4cxx from apache or pantheios which is open source

Comment: Why don't you debug your daemon program on the command line, or in a debugger?

Comment: Chris- I am already using an own local logging mechanism but the problem is when stop signal is received to the program this backtrace is always printing in the console window. like printing the stack trace at a segmentation fault in the program. for now I just need to avoid printing this in the window and save it to an external file.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch- I am debugging the program with valgrind to catch and remove the memory leaks. temporally I am trying to hide the backtrace by saving it into an external file. I need a way to do it using the init script located inside **/etc/init.d**

Comment: Just change your init script to do more relevant or complex things. BTW you should show some code in your question

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch- question is edited to add current init script. I am trying to modify code for start and stop actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the output of the console to another file either using a pipe or `dup()`.

Comment: how to do this using a pipe, I am using an init script (inside /etc/init.d/) to start/stop the service. I have no idea to manage this with a pipe. Do I need to modify the init script ?

Comment: are you suggesting something like this ? **service serviceName stop > path/to/backtraceLogFile**

Comment: I dont have the sample code but using pipe you can connect stdout to a file descriptor. I will try to find. Using dup call & pipe you can redirect the console output.